# Using cin to input a single letter into a char

Tags: c++, arrays, input, char, cin

I have been trying to use "cin" to input a single letter to a char named letter. I have to input the letter using this method, but every time that I outputted the letter after the "cin" line I have a unrecognizable character.

```
int main()
{
char letter[2];
cout << "Enter a letter: ";
cin >> letter;
cout << letter[2];
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a letter: a
▮
```

I also get random character output sometimes, such as "1" and "s".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you want one character, use a `char`, not an array. Also, `letter[2]` is not a valid element in an array of size 2.

Comment: `char letter[2];` is an array if characters, `char letter;` is one character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not inputting or outputting the characters correctly. `char letter[2]` is an array of 2 characters, not a single character. You want `char letter`. Further, you are outputting `letter[2]`, which is the third element of an array that only has two values (indexing in C++ starts from 0; the first element is `letter[0]` and the second is `letter[1]`)! The output will always be garbage. The correct code should be:

```
char letter;
cout << "Enter a letter: ";
cin >> letter;
cout << letter;
return 0;
```

Comment: Technically, the input part is ok **in this one case** because it's one (explicit) character and the array is two. It's way too easy to give input that triggers UB, though.

Answer (score -2):

You just set the length of letters in array, and simply show that.

```
    int main()
    {
    char single[1];
    cout << "Enter any single letter\n";
    cin >> single;
    cout << "Your letter is\n";
    cout << single;
    return 0;
    }
```